# How can I make prediction with Deep Learning model by using new input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to do sentiment analysis by using Deep-Learning algorithms. I have built my own model and made test by using test data. I also should make prediction with the new input. However, I couldn't figure how can I do that ?

Here it is my code:

```
# Tokenization
print(colored("Tokenizing and padding data", "yellow"))
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=2000, split=' ')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_data['Clean_tweet'].astype(str).values)
train_tweets = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_data['Clean_tweet'].astype(str).values)
max_len = max([len(i) for i in train_tweets])
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
train_tweets = pad_sequences(train_tweets, maxlen=max_len)

le = LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(train_data['Sentiment'].values)

test_tweets = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_data['Clean_tweet'].astype(str).values)
test_tweets = pad_sequences(test_tweets, maxlen=max_len)
print(colored("Tokenizing and padding complete", "yellow"))

embeddings_dictionary = dict()
embedding_dim = 100
glove_file = open('glove.6B.100d.txt')

for line in glove_file:
    records = line.split()
    word = records[0]
    vector_dimensions = np.asarray(records[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_dictionary[word] = vector_dimensions

glove_file.close()

embeddings_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_size, embedding_dim))
for word, index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = embeddings_dictionary.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embeddings_matrix[index] = embedding_vector

embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=max_len, weights=[embeddings_matrix],
                            trainable=False)

# Building the model
print(colored("Creating the LSTM model", "yellow"))
model = Sequential()
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(256, dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()


# Training the model
print(colored("Training the LSTM model", "green"))
history = model.fit(train_tweets, pd.get_dummies(train_data['Sentiment']).values, epochs=15, batch_size=256,
                    validation_split=0.2)
print(colored(history, "green"))

model.save('model.h5')
```

And I did something like this for predict new input:

```
text = "I hate you"

seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text)
padded = pad_sequences(seq, maxlen=len(text) + 1)
pred = model.predict_classes(padded)
print(pred)
```

Output is:

```
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

How can I clearly understand what is the sentiment (0 for negative, 1 for Positive sentiment)?

Comment: You need to preprocess the sentence as you did for training set, tokenize etc. Also `model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))` does not seem right, you might need to re-train it.

Comment: text = "I hate you" 
seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text)
padded = pad_sequences(seq, maxlen=len(text) + 1)
pred = model.predict_classes(padded)

I did something like this, but It didn't work as I wanted @Frightera What do you suggest instead of model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')) ?

Comment: What did it output? `model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))`

Comment: @Frightera Output is [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]

Comment: I suggest you to edit the question with this output.

Comment: `model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))` gives me an error by the way @Frightera I edited the question